# Why doesn't SingletonSet implement SortedSet

Tags: java, collections

In order so reduce memory consumption, I'm rewriting a class that has a `SortedSet<Integer>`. In 80% of cases, this collection contains only a single element . So I thought I could use a `SingeltonSet` in these cases and a normal `TreeSet` in other cases. Now I noticed that `SingletonSet`, as returned by [`Collections.singleton()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#singleton-T-), does not implement `SortedSet`. Is there any reason for this shortcoming? A single element can always be considered sorted I'd say. Do I have to write my own `SingletonSet` implementation?

Comment: You could, of course, just write `new TreeSet<E>(Collections.singleton(element))`.

Comment: @VGR Sorry, I guess I forgot to mention that it's all about memory consumption.

Comment: I’m pretty sure you’re engaging in premature optimization.  `new TreeSet` will not impact your performance unless you’re creating millions of them, and quite possibly not even then.

Comment: As a side note, implementing your own singleton set is very simple if you extend [`AbstractSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/AbstractSet.html).

Comment: @VGR There are about 2 million instances and this refactoring is the result of memory analysis insights.

Comment: Consider that the singleton passed to a TreeSet constructor has no references to it once the constructor completes.  This means it is immediately eligible for garbage collection.  So the net memory usage is nearly the same.

Comment: @VGR The problem isn't that collections aren't garbage collected. The problem is memory consumption of the 2 million instances. I don't understand why people are so eagerly judging whether things are superfluous or premature or whatever. BTW I just made a minitest. 2 millions TreeSets with 1 integer occupied 280M, 2 million SingletonSets just 80m.

Comment: If you're really trying to optimize memory usage, it's perfectly fine to dig down into the the type hierarchy and just directly store your one element for your 80% case. You can lazily generate the relevant (potentially custom) wrapper for the retrieval methods.

Comment: @pvg thanks, that's an option. I have many accesses well though.

Comment: @steffen well. At that point it's pretty difficult to tell what your intended performance profile is, what you've measured, where you want to get to, etc. My point is mostly 'if you're very heavily into optimization, you probably shouldn't worry too much about abstraction barriers'.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is an interesting point, which seems to illustrate a small hole in the collections API.

The fact is that `Collections.singleton()` is specified to return a `Set`, not a `SortedSet`, and in fact the implementation doesn't support that interface. I don't think it would be helpful for `Collections.singleton()` to change its behavior and return an instance of a `SortedSet`. This would encourage implementations to perform `instanceof` checks and downcasting. (And similar for the corresponding Map methods and interfaces.)

It's a small consolation for this use case, but in Java SE 8 new methods `Collections.emptyNavigableMap` and `emptyNavigableSet` were introduced. This is helpful for use cases that want empty navigable collections, but if you really want a navigable with a single element or mapping, you're out of luck. There's an enhancement request [JDK-6201174](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-6201174) that covers a similar area; I've updated and refocused it around providing APIs for a singleton navigable set and map.

But wait! As you [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44399973/1441122), there is a bit of additional state that rides along with sorted/navigable collections, which is the comparator. (Or in the absence of a comparator, implicitly one that provides natural ordering.) Any new singleton APIs would have a provide for that as well. And this points out the fact that the empty* methods I mentioned above don't talk about the Comparator. That seems like another bug: [JDK-8181754](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8181754).

Unfortunately I don't have a really good workaround for you other than to buckle down and implement a one-element, possibly immutable SortedSet or NavigableSet. You could start off with [`Collections.UnmodifiableNavigableSet`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/Collections.java#l1263). This helps a little, but not much. In fact, the empty navigable set is one of these wrapped around an empty `TreeSet`! This is quite unhelpful, since you want to avoid `TreeSet` instances.

I'd probably start from AbstractSet and then add the minimal set of methods from SortedSet. There are rather fewer methods than in NavigableSet, so if you don't need all of its bells and whistles, it'd be a smaller task to stick to SortedSet.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comprehensive answer and motivation for analyzing this topic! I can't +2, so +1 +✓. I think I'll either check out fastutil or write my own `Sorted-` or `NavigableSingleton`. One thing I did not get: Why does a more specialized return type encourage `instanceof` checks?

Comment: You're welcome! The issue with the return value from `Collections.singleton` is that the static return type cannot be changed for compatibility reasons. The implementation however could be changed to return an instance of (say) `SortedSet` even though the static return type is `Set`. But to use it as a `SortedSet` programmers would have to test `instanceof` and downcast. It's much preferable to add a new API with a more specific static return type.

Comment: Sure thing. And returning a more specialized type would break binary compatibility. Got it.

Answer (score 8):

The [`SortedSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/SortedSet.html) interface defines methods that require a [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) for the set elements. Thus elements maintained by a `SortedSet` have to be comparable. If the singleton returned by `Collections.singleton()` would implement `SortedSet`, then `Collections.singleton()` could accept [`Comparables`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) only (which is not what we want).

Comment: +1 for pointing out that the Sorted and Navigable interfaces imply a hidden state, which is the Comparator.

Answer (score 1):

I think Stuart Marks's answer explains very well why there is no singleton for sorted set.
However, it is not difficult to implement a SingletonSortedSet.

What about:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.function.Consumer;
import java.util.function.Predicate;

public class SingletonSortedSet<E>
        extends AbstractSet<E>
        implements SortedSet<E> {
    private final E element;
    private final Comparator<? super E> comparator;

    private SingletonSortedSet(E e, Comparator<? super E> comparator) {
        element = e;
        this.comparator = comparator;
    }

    public static <E> SortedSet<E> singletonSortedSet(E e, Comparator<? super E> comparator) {
        return new SingletonSortedSet<>(e, comparator);
    }

    public Iterator<E> iterator() {
        return singletonIterator(element);
    }

    public int size() {
        return 1;
    }

    public boolean contains(Object o) {
        return Objects.equals(o, element);
    }

    // Override default methods for Collection
    @Override
    public void forEach(Consumer<? super E> action) {
        action.accept(element);
    }

    @Override
    public Spliterator<E> spliterator() {
        return singletonSpliterator(element, comparator);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean removeIf(Predicate<? super E> filter) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hashCode(element);
    }

    @Override
    public Comparator<? super E> comparator() {
        return comparator;
    }

    @Override
    public SortedSet<E> subSet(E fromElement, E toElement) {
        if(contains(fromElement) || contains(toElement)) {
            return this;
        } else {
            return Collections.emptySortedSet();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public SortedSet<E> headSet(E toElement) {
        if(contains(toElement)) {
            return this;
        } else {
            return Collections.emptySortedSet();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public SortedSet<E> tailSet(E fromElement) {
        if(contains(fromElement)) {
            return this;
        } else {
            return Collections.emptySortedSet();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public E first() {
        return element;
    }

    @Override
    public E last() {
        return element;
    }

    private static <E> Iterator<E> singletonIterator(final E e) {
        return new Iterator<E>() {
            private boolean hasNext = true;
            public boolean hasNext() {
                return hasNext;
            }
            public E next() {
                if (hasNext) {
                    hasNext = false;
                    return e;
                }
                throw new NoSuchElementException();
            }
            public void remove() {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
            }
            @Override
            public void forEachRemaining(Consumer<? super E> action) {
                Objects.requireNonNull(action);
                if (hasNext) {
                    hasNext = false;
                    action.accept(e);
                }
            }
        };
    }

    private static <T> Spliterator<T> singletonSpliterator(final T element, Comparator<? super T> comparator) {
        return new Spliterator<T>() {
            long est = 1;

            @Override
            public Spliterator<T> trySplit() {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean tryAdvance(Consumer<? super T> consumer) {
                Objects.requireNonNull(consumer);
                if (est > 0) {
                    est--;
                    consumer.accept(element);
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void forEachRemaining(Consumer<? super T> consumer) {
                tryAdvance(consumer);
            }

            @Override
            public long estimateSize() {
                return est;
            }

            @Override
            public int characteristics() {
                int value = (element != null) ? Spliterator.NONNULL : 0;

                return value | Spliterator.SIZED | Spliterator.SUBSIZED | Spliterator.IMMUTABLE |
                        Spliterator.DISTINCT | Spliterator.SORTED;
            }

            @Override
            public Comparator<? super T> getComparator() {
                return comparator;
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Then you can use SingletonSortedSet.singletonSortedSet(...).

Answer (score 0):

Nice impl. mmirwaldt! I went ahead and created my own and posted it at https://github.com/hammerspaceinc/hs-java-utils. It requires that the element/class being held by the SingletonSortedSet implement Comparable, which was true for my use-cases.